# CU July2015 Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException Error

Tags: feature-upgrade, patching

In SP 2013 Enterprise (DB and WFE separate server) after installing CU July2015 and rebooting using dbowner / farm admin account I execute the cmdlets

```
psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b
```

as describe on installation notes but it throws exception error. With the error Central Admin and site are down

SERVICE LOGS *************************************

Log Name:      Application
Source:        SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard
Date:          11/18/2015 8:17:38 AM
Event ID:      104
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      portal.xxx.local
Description:
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
Event Xml:

  
    
    104
    2
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    382869
    Application
    portal.gpzgroup.local
    
  
  
    Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The upgrade command is invalid or a failure has been encountered.
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the CU on all sharepoint servers? (Not the DB server). If so, try to first run  "Get-SPProduct -local" on all the Sp servers and then try again.

Comment: Thanks. 

Got it fixed. I run the SP management shell as administrator and run the same cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Run SP management shell as administrator and run the same cmdlet

```
psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b
```